# Copy events from one Google Calendar to another, without duplication

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm working on building some logic between a couple calendars.

- Get my calendar,
- If event title contains "Install",

  - Create event on InstallCalendar.

I'm getting stuck after retrieving the two calendars. I'm not sure how to gracefully add the logic I have in comments at the bottom.

```js
function copyInstalls(){
  var now = new Date();
  var later = new Date("January 1, 2015 08:00:00 PDT"); // be lazy for now

  // get my calendar to see whether I have install events scheduled 
  var my_calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var my_install_events =  
  CalendarApp.getCalendarById('example@group.calendar.google.com').getEvents(now, later, {search: 'Install'});


  // snag the Installation Events calendar 
  var install_calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('example@group.calendar.google.com');
  var install_events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('example@group.calendar.google.com').getEvents(now, later, {search: 'Install'});  

  for (var event in my_install_events){

     // if it doesn't exist in install_events, create a new event
     // Not sure how to do this part

  }

}
```

Comment: I have the same idea/need and I don't know where to start, otherwise I might be of more help to you.  I did create a new thread, perhaps I might get some useful info you could use, maybe not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764973/multiple-google-calendars-script-to-change-calendars-ased-on-event-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be clear about what criteria would identify whether one of your "Install" events is already on the InstallCalendar. Since your intent is to reproduce a copy of the original event, we can't expect that the event ID will be the same. (However, if you *invited* the InstallCalendar instead, it would be - and better yet, rescheduling would be automatically reflected.)

We could assume that matching "Install" in the subject + identical start times is sufficient for a match. But then rescheduling on one calendar would orphan the event on the other, leading to duplication.

A better choice is to apply a custom tag to the event in InstallCalendar, setting it to the ID of the original event for convenience. Then we just need to search through all the previously-set tags looking for a match for event IDs from `my_calendar`. To prepare for this, we can build an array of those tags:

```js
  // build array of event tags for comparison
  var install_event_Tags = [];
  install_events.forEach( function (event) {
    install_event_Tags.push(event.getTag('origID'));
  });
```

With that done, here's how we'd ensure we copy events exactly once:

```js
  ...
  my_install_events.forEach( function (event) {
     // if it doesn't exist in install_events, create a new event
    var eventId = event.getId();
    var match = install_event_Tags.indexOf(eventId);
    if (match === -1) {
      // Duplicate the event from my_calendar
      var newEvent = install_calendar.createEvent(event.getTitle(), event.getStartTime(), event.getEndTime());
      // Apply a tag with original event ID
      newEvent.setTag('origID', eventId);
    }
  });
```

#### Other issues

There appear to be other problems in your code that you should address.

1. When retrieving `my_install_events`, you are opening the shared `example` calendar, which is also used later for `install_events`.

   ```
     // get my calendar to see whether I have install events scheduled 
     var my_calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
     var my_install_events =  
     CalendarApp.getCalendarById('example@group.calendar.google.com').getEvents(now, later, {search: 'Install'});
   ```

   Perhaps you mean...

   ```
     // get my calendar to see whether I have install events scheduled 
     var my_calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
     var my_install_events = my_calendar.getEvents(now, later, {search: 'Install'});
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```
2. Not a bug, per se, but repeating the call to `getCalendarById` will slow your code. Since you've calculated `install_calendar`, may as well use it.

   ```
   // snag the Installation Events calendar 
   var install_calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('example@group.calendar.google.com');
   var install_events = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('example@group.calendar.google.com').getEvents(now, later, {search: 'Install'});
   ```

   More easily maintained:

   ```
   // snag the Installation Events calendar 
   var install_calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('example@group.calendar.google.com');
   var install_events = install_calendar.getEvents(now, later, {search: 'Install'});  
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

#### Final script

```js
function copyInstalls(){
  var now = new Date();
  var later = new Date("January 1, 2015 08:00:00 PDT"); // be lazy for now

  // get my calendar to see whether I have install events scheduled 
  var my_calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  var my_install_events = my_calendar.getEvents(now, later, {search: 'Install'});

  // snag the Installation Events calendar 
  var install_calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('example@group.calendar.google.com');
  var install_events = install_calendar.getEvents(now, later, {search: 'Install'});

  // build array of event tags for comparison
  var install_event_Tags = [];
  install_events.forEach( function (event) {
    install_event_Tags.push(event.getTag('origID'));
  });

  my_install_events.forEach( function (event) {
     // if it doesn't exist in install_events, create a new event
    var eventId = event.getId();
    var match = install_event_Tags.indexOf(eventId);
    if (match === -1) {
      // Duplicate the event from my_calendar
      var newEvent = install_calendar.createEvent(event.getTitle(), event.getStartTime(), event.getEndTime());
      // Apply a tag with original event ID
      newEvent.setTag('origID', eventId);
    }
  });
}
```

#### Next steps

This script will make unique copies of Install events from `my_calendar` to `InstallCalendar`. That may be sufficient for your needs. However, there are additional scenarios you might want to consider:

- What if the Install event exists in `InstallCalendar`, but was rescheduled?
- What if an event previously copied to `InstallCalendar` gets deleted from `my_calendar`?
- What if an event previously copied to `InstallCalendar` gets deleted there? The current script would copy it again, but maybe the desired behavior is to delete it from `my_calendar` as well.

Comment: Wow, thank you Mogsdad. This walkthrough is fantastic. I realize the problem I needed to solve is only part of the scenario and your next steps are dead on. Cheers!