# Multiple Google Calendars, script to change calendars based on event name

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a work around for Google not allowing anyone to add to a global calendar, so I started doing research and found [eventbot](https://myeventbot-hrd.appspot.com/), which allows me to add a meeting based on an email that I send.

Here is what I imagine, but I don't know how to work it.

- I have two different global calendars
- Using a QR Code and that email address eventbot gave me, the code is scanned, the type in the needed subject line, and the event is created on my personal calendar.

Here comes where I am in need of advice:

- Each event will have a phrase (Sisters/Brothers), if my calendar sees the word "Sisters", it will change the default calendar from my personal to the "Sisters" Calendar, or "Brothers" same thing.

It seems like a simple enough task, I am just not familiar enough with Google to know where to start, or to put my script in my google account. I also don't know if there is an API I could use.

Has anyone else thought of this? Any ideas on where to begin?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works better for me and is a better approch, but doesn't answer my original question:
http://librariansonthefly.blogspot.com/2013/12/creating-google-calendar-appointments.html